# In Eclipse Neon, Is there any easy way to know the declaration of a parameter when calling a method?

Tags: eclipse, methods, eclipse-neon

When calling a method with many arguments (10), i would like to be able to know which argument i am hovering over/clicking on without counting the arguments.

for example, let's say we have this method:

public void method1(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4)

our code uses:
this.method1("arg1test", "arg2test", null, "arg4test")
is there a  way to hover over/click null and know that is declared as "String arg3"?

Thanks for your help